# Efficient way to check which array rows fall between the values of two other vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large numpy array of shape `(20, 702000)`, and I need to find which rows have values that fall between two other arrays. In the following simplified example,

```
a = np.array([[1,3,4,3,2,4],
              [4,6,2,5,8,6],
              [1,4,8,3,1,9],
              [9,4,2,5,6,5]])

range_low = np.array([0,2,3,2,1,3])
range_high = np.array([2,4,5,4,3,5])
```

`a[0]` is the only row that would fit the criteria and fall between `range_low` and `range_high` for each number.

I have tried something like,

```
[np.where(np.logical_and(x > range_low, x < range_high)) for x in a]
```

and it works, but in such a large array looping takes a very long time. Is there a quicker way to do something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you want all row indices that fit the critera?
Then i would suggest this:

```py
np.flatnonzero(((a > range_low) & (a < range_high)).all(axis=1))
```

If you have numpy version 1.20.0 you can also use the `where` keyword for [numpy.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html#numpy.all).

Answer (score 0):

Quicker:

```
[np.where(x) for x in np.logical_and(a > range_low, a < range_high)]
```

Even quicker, but different format output:

```
np.where(np.logical_and(a > range_low, a < range_high))
```

Times:

```
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [np.where(np.logical_and(x > range_low, x < range_high)) for x in a], number=100000)) # 1.3141384999999999
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: [np.where(x) for x in np.logical_and(a > range_low, a < range_high)], number=100000)) # 1.0557419000000001
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: np.where(np.logical_and(a > range_low, a < range_high)), number=100000)) # 0.4683885000000001
```